# Invalid URI at getting path in different android api

Tags: android

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton, PID: 22721
>                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/P/B/JPEG_20160115_170005_776674531.jpg
>                                                                                            at android.provider.DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(DocumentsContract.java:752)
>                                                                                            at ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(RealPathUtil.java:19)
>                                                                                            at ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.DeliverActivity.createImageFile(DeliverActivity.java:428)
>                                                                                            at ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.DeliverActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(DeliverActivity.java:298)
>                                                                                            at ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.DeliverActivity.onClick(DeliverActivity.java:248)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

My code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Prokaton/Big");
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
        mCurrentPhotoPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, Uri.fromFile(image));

        // SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
        mCurrentPhotoPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, Uri.fromFile(image));

        // SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
    else
        mCurrentPhotoPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, Uri.fromFile(image));
    ...
}
```

RealPathUtilClass :

public class RealPathUtil {

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String result = null;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
            context,
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if(cursor != null){
        int column_index =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index
            = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

Im trying to use this exaple http://hmkcode.com/android-display-selected-image-and-its-real-path/
but i dont need this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // 2. pick image only
    intent.setType("image/*");
    // 3. start activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this code inside your method, (use same code for all API versions)

Hope it will help you out

```
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { 
            result = uri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
```